# How should I properly include the same file across multiple directories?

Tags: php, include, relative-path, include-path, absolute-path

I'm currently working on a very simple multipage PHP website with a basic directory structure. Much like this:

```
/
- index.php
- config.php
- services/
  - index.php
  - service-a.php
  - service-b.php
- projects/
  - index.php
  - project-name/
    - index.php
    - testimonials.php
- common/
  - head.php
- js/
- img/
- css/
```

Unfortunately my local development environment and the production environment do not match structurally due to the addition of an extra local folder.
Therefore I created `config.php` - which I placed in the location I deem the root folder - containing the following:

```
define('ROOT_DIR', __DIR__);
define('ROOT_URL', ($_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] == "localhost") ? "http://localhost/website/" : "https://website.com/");
```

These constants allow me to create absolute paths - on my local and remote environment - to any file I include, wether it's another PHP file or an image or stylesheet. That's great because I want to avoid any relative paths as much as possible.

Se here's the issue:
I need to include the config file in every page in order for the constants to work.
For the homepage (`/index.php`) that's not a big deal. I just add this to the top of the file:

`<?php include_once('config.php'); ?>`

However, for a page in a subdirectory (`/services/index.php`) I'd have to use a relative path to the config file, which is something I'd like to avoid:

`<?php include_once('../config.php'); ?>`

If we go even deeper, like `/projects/project-name/index.php`, I'd have to include it like this:

`<?php include_once('../../config.php'); ?>`

It works but it doesn't seem/feel correct. **How should I declare the path to an included file that defines how paths to included files should be declared?**

After searching for for hours I still haven't found an answer. If someone has an answer or could point me in the right direction, please let me know.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't feel right!! It's right. That's how you include a file.

Comment: But if that's the way it should be, why bother using absolute paths at all for any file?
Like, I could also link to a stylesheet via ../../css/base.css just fine.

I was told to avoid relative paths as much as possible to accommodate for scalability and moving around pages. That's what I'm trying to do everywhere.